# UIScrollView does not work with MFSideMenu library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, mfslidemenu

I need to implement, sidemenu featured application.

I have added **MFSideMenu** library to my project. I am putting something to its containerviewcontroller in which there is a `scrollview`.

But `scrollview` does not scroll.

I am setting content size of `scrollview` in a method of view controller.

How can i solve this?

Note: I am using storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in my project by using  a UITableViewController as a child view controller with 1 static UITableViewCell, it made me possible to design a screen as long as I needed.